# Redirecting as proxy one subfolder of apache server to azure web app

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, azure-webapps, azure-custom-domain

I have a website on apache web server, and I would like one of subfolders to transparently redirect to azure web app.

- mydomain.org -> regular apache page
- mydomain.org/something -> regular apache page
- mydomain.org/azure  -> redirect to azure

However, **I would need the url to stay on mydomain.org**, so I would like - for example mydomain.com/azure/x/y to actually show result of azuredomain.org/x/y

I believe I can do it using .htaccess with rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ azuredomain.org/$1 [P]`

However, this results in azure 404 error with suggestion that maybe "Custom domain has not been configured inside Azure", which is in fact correct.

**Is it possible to configure 'mydomain.org ' as custom domain in azure, but only for one subfolder** (mydomain.org /azure/) while allowing all other urls to map to apache server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work:

1. Create subdomain 'azure' pointing to folder 'azure'
2. Add .htaccess to 'azure' folder with rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ azuredomain.org/$1 [P]`
3. Add records to domain:

- TXT / asuid.azure / [verificationID]
- CNAME / azure / azuredomain.org

4. In Web App settings add custom domain with subdomain: azure.mydomain.org